# Strange consequences of "ref" keyword in C# to COM interop

Tags: c#, windows, com, interop, com-interop

Consider an excerpt from code that can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/winsearchfile.aspx):

```
namespace WinSearchFile
{
    public class Parser
    {
        [DllImport("query.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] 
        private extern static int LoadIFilter (string pwcsPath, ref IUnknown pUnkOuter, ref IFilter ppIUnk); 

        [ComImport, Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")] 
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)] 
        private interface IUnknown 
        { 
            [PreserveSig] 
            IntPtr QueryInterface( ref Guid riid, out IntPtr pVoid ); 
            [PreserveSig] 
            IntPtr AddRef(); 
            [PreserveSig] 
            IntPtr Release(); 
        } 

        private static IFilter loadIFilter(string filename)
        {
            IUnknown iunk = null; 
            IFilter filter = null;

            // Try to load the corresponding IFilter 
            int resultLoad = LoadIFilter( filename, ref iunk, ref filter ); 
            if (resultLoad != (int)IFilterReturnCodes.S_OK) 
            { 
                return null;
            } 
            return filter;
        }
  }
```

`Parser::loadIFilter()` in that code basically calls [LoadIFilter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691002(VS.85).aspx) function. The latter looks up the registry, finds which class id corresponds to the specified file extension, instantiates a corresponding COM class (calls `CoCreateInstance()`) and calls `IPersistFile::Load()` from it.

Now the problem is that the signature for `LoadIFilter()` is the following:

```
HRESULT __stdcall LoadIFilter( PCWSTR pwcsPath, __in IUnknown *pUnkOuter, __out void **ppIUnk );
```

so the second parameter is `IUnknown*` of the aggregating object. If the COM class for the extension of interest doesn't support aggregation and the `IUnknown*` passed is not null `CoCreateInstance()` returns `CLASS_E_NOAGGREGATION` and so does `LoadIFilter()`.

If I remove the `ref` keyword from the `pUnkOuter` parameter in the declaration and at the site of `LoadIFilter()` call the function is called with null `IUnknown*`. If I retain the `ref` keyword the function is called with non-null `IUnknown*` and returns `CLASS_E_NOAGGREGATION` for classes that don't support aggregation.

My question is - why is non-null `IUnknown*` passed when the keyword is retained? `IUnknown iunk` local variable is initialized to `null` so where does non-null `IUnknown*` come from in the invoked unmanaged code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ref is simply wrong, your IUnknown is already passed as a pointer since it is an interface.  Passing ref would be equivalent to IUnknown**

Comment: So do you mean that they effectively pass the address of the local variable and that address which corresponds to `IUnknown**` in C++ terms is interpreted as `IUnknown*` by the callee so that the latter risks full-blown undefined behavior?

Comment: That sounds horrible yet quite reasonable. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `ref`, you're not actually sending in the `null`, you're sending in a reference to where that `null` is stored, but when you're sending in without the `ref` you're sending in the actual value, which is `null`.

So:

With ref it's a reference to a null pointer.

Without it it's just a null pointer.

Edit: If I understand your question correctly, which I'm not 100% certain off...

Answer (score 1):

The non-null bit comes from inside the method - it is instantiating an object onto the reference you've provided.  Using the ref keyword on a reference type will pass the callers reference to the object, not creating another reference to the object (which is what happens when you pass by reference normally).  Try this:

```
static void Main()
{
    object foo = null;
    SetMyObject(ref foo);

    bool test = foo == null;
}

public static void SetMyObject(ref object foo)
{
    foo = new object();
}
```

The variable test will be false.